# Recent email send summary sendstart and sendcomplete difference

Tags: marketing-cloud, reports-folder

We send daily Welcome emails however when i run the **Recent email send summary** report over a period to get a monthly breakdown and report on its stats i find for some emails the start and end time are very different and the results are combined into the same row.

1. Why is this happening?
2. What would be another way to get the email send summary and its metrics over a period of time

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Assuming these emails are Triggered Sends, it's likely that the start and end time represent the lifecycle of the JobID and when the Triggered Send Definition was published.

Triggered Send JobIDs do persist and only change when you re-publish the definition (or update a Journey email or create a new Journey version).

You could retrieve the Send SOAP API object data for your account and see how they change over time -- this data is the source for the Recent Sending Summary.  Here's a sample SOAP call I wrote in Postman:

```xml
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: https://YOURTENANTHERE.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx
Content-Type: text/xml

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://YOURTENANTHERE.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">YOURTOKENHERE</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <Options>
                    <Client>
                        <ClientID>YOURMIDHERE</ClientID>
                    </Client>
                </Options>
                <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>SendDate</Properties>
                <Properties>FromAddress</Properties>
                <Properties>FromName</Properties>
                <Properties>Duplicates</Properties>
                <Properties>InvalidAddresses</Properties>
                <Properties>ExistingUndeliverables</Properties>
                <Properties>ExistingUnsubscribes</Properties>
                <Properties>HardBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>SoftBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>OtherBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>ForwardedEmails</Properties>
                <Properties>UniqueClicks</Properties>
                <Properties>UniqueOpens</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberSent</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberDelivered</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberTargeted</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberErrored</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberExcluded</Properties>
                <Properties>Unsubscribes</Properties>
                <Properties>MissingAddresses</Properties>
                <Properties>Subject</Properties>
                <Properties>PreviewURL</Properties>
                <Properties>SentDate</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailName</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>IsMultipart</Properties>
                <Properties>SendLimit</Properties>
                <Properties>IsAlwaysOn</Properties>
                <Properties>Additional</Properties>
                <Properties>BCCEmail</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>SendWindowOpen</Properties>
                <Properties>SendWindowClose</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

If you want to automate the storage of this data, I've outlined a way to do that [**here on my blog**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/retrieving-and-storing-aggregated-send-data/).

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you for that. You are right they are journey sends. I made some changes to the email in May and July however prior to that the same report was showing me a daily breakdown as they were being sent (see screenshot). How do i re-achieve this whre a separate jobiD is created per send. I guess i could extract the dataviews into a DE and join them but i like the format of this report that is readily available. **Sorry the screenshot didnt come through**

Comment: You'd have to republish the email every day to force a JobID change.  Data views will show the same behavior.

Comment: When analyzing SFMC tracking data by date you always want to start at the activity (send, open, click, etc.) and go back to the Job, not the other way around.  Triggered Send based JobIDs do not accurately reflect time.

Comment: Thanks mate, there are so many nuances with MC and its good to learn how it behaves.